# Find string values with colon in solr

Tags: solr

I have a text field with value "rr:34:56". I tried the following query via the REST API without any success.

q=rr\\:3* - query returns nothing. debug returns ""rawquerystring": "rr\\:3*",
    "querystring": "rr\\:3*",
    "parsedquery": "text:rr:3*".

Parser is LuceneQParser.

So the question is following. How can i find string fields with colons in it?

Comment: How is the analyzer of that field? It might be that those colons are stripped away. You will find all of this in your schema.xml

Comment: @cheffe could you please be more specific? at what part of schema.xml i should look at?

Comment: without trailing asterix debug returns another parsedquery "parsedquery": "text:rr text:34". in this case query returns document.

Comment: @nem : Did you analysed it with solr tool. like whats the end string of indexing and query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case solution was to switch from LuceneQParser to edismax and passes "text" in qf.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you indexed that field as a "StrField" you should escape the colon by using a single backslash (e.g. rr:12\:23)

Comment: I'm escaping colon with single slash.

Comment: Sorry my backslash has been escaped :) backslash, not slash

Answer (score 0):

The query format is correct (meaning that rr:33 would query for the value `rr:33`), but you're not querying any particular field, so the search is performed against your default field. This may not give you the result you want (easy check, search for `rr*`), and you probably want `fieldname:rr\:34*` instead.

Comment: I need to search against all fields, so there is no any particular field.

Comment: Use qf to provide the list of fields to search, or have all your values copyField-ed to a field for searching. Not providing a field name will *not* search all fields, just the default search field.

Comment: rr* gives me all documents with rr:34:56. the type of the field is string. i've noticed that search returns nothing even without special characters in string. for example rr#34#56. rr* - returns rr#34#56. but rr#* - returns nothing. and i'm just wondering may be the problem in string type?

Comment: Sounds like your field isn't a StrField, and that your fields are tokenized. Wildcard matches are performed on a per token basis, so rr#* won't match if the field has been tokenized to be rr / 34 / 56 as separate tokens. Use a direct StrField instead.